# Utility class for temporary error information storage?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

I have been writing a light-weight framework to wrap the Windows API for personal projects and some fun. What I think is a good design method is that each class in the framework manages its own error information whenever something goes wrong. I have a simple error class like so:

```
class Error
{
public:

    struct ErrorData
    {
        DWORD       sysErrCode;
        tstring     sysErrStr;
        SYSTEMTIME  localTime;
        tstring     errMsg;
        tstring     funcCall;
        tstring     parentClass;
    };
    void getErrorData(ErrorData *pErrorData);
    Error(const tstring parentClass);
    void setErrorData(const tstring errMsg, const tstring funcCall, const bool getSysErr = false);

private:

    ErrorData errorData;
    void getSystemError(DWORD &sysErrCode, tstring &sysErrStr);
};
```

What I'm stuck on is how to incorporate this class into the other classes. Inheritance sounds wrong because a dialog class is not an Error class. Composition sounds better, a dialog class can have an Error class. But then I'm stuck writing a getter function for every class to retrieve the Error class's information. Although that would only take a short time to write, there has got to be a better design method. I would rather not have to copy and paste those functions in every class either.

Any ideas would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Use exceptions. Also take a look at Boost.Exception.

Comment: "What I think is a good design method is that each class in the framework manages its own error information whenever something goes wrong" - maybe you are discovering that this is not such a good idea after all?

Comment: I didn't think of using exceptions for it. Basically if the framework calls CreateWindow() or GetWindowText() or even user input validation for setting information fails, the framework class simply calls setErrorData(), passing in what was trying to be accomplished, getSystemError called during the execution of that function if desired. That way I can use getErrorData() to retrieve the information if I want to. All error info is stored in each class to keep it out of the way.

Comment: Do you really want to treat error data as part of each class rather than as information describing what went wrong on an *operation*?

Comment: @rem45acp  You can create very rich sub-classes of Exception that can contain all the information you need to describe the error.  Having such data stored in the exception itself seems pretty out of the way to me...

Comment: @dusktreader You can, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using exceptions and `throw`ing your `ErrorData` class instead? That seems better than either inheritance or composition.

It almost looks like `getSystemError` should be a namespace free-function instead of a member (it looks like everything it needs is passed into its parameters).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to recommend using Exceptions for error management.  You could have one exception type that is used unilaterally in your application, or you could create a hierarchy of exception types that are specialized for specific classes.

If you don't want to go down that route, you can still get away from having to implement a special getter function for errors in each of your classes, you **can** use inheritance pretty painlessly.  Just make a base class that all objects with error management inherit from, and implement a getter once in the base class:

```
class ErrorManager
{
    const Error& getError();
    void setError( Error& err );  // Or however you would actually set the error
}

class Widget : public ErrorManager
{
    // Implementation details
}

Widget w;
w.getError()
```

While you think that inheritance seems wrong, it is really quite appropriate.  You are correct that a Dialog is not an Error.  However, it does **have-a** Error, and you can manage interaction with that error by using inheritance.  Therefore, your dialog **is-a** ErrorManager because it uses a common framework for managing its errors.

Good Luck!

Comment: This still isn't what inheritance is for. You should inherit for substitutability, and this does not seem to fit that role.

Comment: You are completely incorrect in that regard.  Inheritance is also a powerful tool that can be used to create common interfaces for classes that have similar behavior.  This is, in fact, a text-book case for inheritance.  If many classes in his application use the same sort of error management, then they should inherit from a common base-class.  This principle is used universally in Java.  C++ doesn't have an explicit native interface mechanism, but inheritance works very well for that purpose.

Comment: @dusktreader From your other answers here you seem to know very little about C++. Perhaps keeping quiet and learning from people that know far more than you would be a good idea?

Comment: @Neil Is that a question or an assertion?  Inheritance and its proper use is a controversial topic.  Perhaps you disagree, but I don't think you can safely assert that I am categorically wrong.  As for my "other" answers, I hastily answered a different question earlier today which I promptly rescinded and deleted.  I didn't think the purpose of this website was to put on airs and condescend, but to help people.

Comment: @dusktreader The use of inheritance is not at all controversial - the gathered wisdom is - never use it if you can avoid doing so.

Comment: @Neil  I'm sorry, but that's just silly.  You shouldn't use inheritance if it has no utility for your purpose.  However, one of the original reasons that inheritance was developed as a OOP construct was to take advantage of **code re-use**, and that is the reason I am recommending it here.  I am assuming that the OP's Error class has a lot more methods than just a getter, and it **would** be ridiculous to reimplement the same behavior in all of those classes.

Comment: @dusktreader You seem to know as little about OOP as you do about C++ - inheritance was not introduced to foster code reuse, it was introduced to provide run-time polymorphism.

Comment: @Neil  You are being both ostentatious and inaccurate.  Run-time polymorphism is only one of the primary benefits.  Code-reuse is another.

Comment: @dusktreader, @Neil: it's a sad fact that in C++ free-wheeling use of public inheritance for code-reuse has maintainability/safety issues that make it undesirable for classes that have widely distributed usage (e.g. low-level enterprise libraries).  Still, the code reuse potential may make it a clear net win in more localised application-level situations or in support of "private" implementation where the potential client-dependency and abuse issues can't be managed or resolved easily.  It's painful to expose access methods in composition.  See Marshall Cline's C++ FAQ for some specifics.

Comment: @Neil: "inherentence... not [for] code reuse, [rather] polymorphism".  That's excessive.  Polymorphism itself is a mechanism for code reuse, and for practical code maintainability the ability to provide only a delta from base-class behaviour and have other function implementations provided transparently by the base is essential.

Comment: @Tony No, that isn't correct. Many (most?) polymorphic classes do not reuse base class stuff. Hence the popularity of pure virtual functions.

Comment: @Neil: well, it's common in many of the applications and problem domains I've worked in to see a mix of non-virtual, virtual and pure virtual functions.  It's a dangerous thing to think you know how other people use C++ and make sweeping statements ;-P.

Comment: @Neil: Less rushed now :-).  "I say this, you say that" discussions achieve little, so a few examples: `istream` only has `virtual` destructor, many non-virtual functions, data (e.g. supporting `gcount()`), and is in the middle of a public inheritance chain; Alexandrescu MC++D mentions derivation from policies as a way to expose a run-time API controlling their operation; `boost` has `progress_timer : public timer { ...; std::ostream& x; };` despite `timer`'s member data and lack of `virtual` functions.  It all works fine on balance, no?